# How to get a WMS GetfeatureInfo popup with OpenLayers?

Tags: geoserver, wms, openlayers-2, popup, getfeatureinfo

I am new to OpenLayers, used this [link](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/getfeatureinfo-popup.html) to get feature information of WMS layer of GeoServer. If I clicked on any feature its continuously loading not displaying any popup. Can any one please help me in this regard. Here is my code

```
<pre><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Religious in Rajahmundry</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="openlayers/theme/default/style.css"
    type="text/css"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="openlayers/examples/style.css"
    type="text/css"></link>
<script src="openlayers/lib/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

var apiKey = "AqTGBsziZHIJYYxgivLBf0hVdrAk9mWO5cQcb8Yux8sW5M8c8opEC2lZqKR1ZZXf";
var map, info, query;
var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
var toProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");
var baseLayer, hospitality, health, religious, communityUtils, education, others, road;

function init() {
    map = new OpenLayers.Map("map");
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine());

    var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("OSM Map");
    Visualization();
    map.addLayer(osm);

    var aerial = new OpenLayers.Layer.Bing({
        key: apiKey,
        type: "Aerial"
    });
    map.addLayer(aerial);

    map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(81.7800, 16.9800).transform(
            fromProjection, toProjection), 12);

        }

function Visualization() {
    baseLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("RJY base layer",
            "http://192.168.1.1:8181/geoserver/rjy/wms", {
                layers : 'rjy:base map',
                format : "image/png",
                styles : '',
                tiled : 'true',
                transparent : true,
                tilesOrigin : map.maxExtent.left + ','
                        + map.maxExtent.bottom
            }, {
                projection : toProjection,
                "isBaseLayer" : false
            });

    map.addLayer(baseLayer);

    religious = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Religious",
            "http://192.168.1.1:8181/geoserver/rjy/wms", {
                layers : 'rjy:religious',
                format : "image/png",
                styles : '',
                tiled : 'true',
                transparent : true,
                tilesOrigin : map.maxExtent.left + ','
                        + map.maxExtent.bottom
            }, {
                projection : toProjection,
                "isBaseLayer" : false
            });
    map.addLayer(religious);


     info = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
            url: 'http://192.168.1.1:8181/geoserver/rjy/wms', 
            title: 'Identify features by clicking',
            queryVisible: true,
            eventListeners: {
                getfeatureinfo: function(event) {
                    map.addPopup(new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
                        "chicken", 
                        map.getLonLatFromPixel(event.xy),
                        null,
                        event.text,
                        null,
                        true
                    ));
                }
            }
        });
        map.addControl(info);
        info.activate();
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">    
    <div id="map" class="smallmap"></div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried to run [example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/getfeatureinfo-popup.html) through my pc, I am getting all layers but did not get popup.

Comment: I had to make sure GetFeatureInfo was enabled on my WMS service on ArcGIS server before I could query features. Might be worth checking you have it enabled. Although it may be different for geoserver, which I haven't used before.

Comment: It might be proxy issue, can anyone help me to set proxy of openlayers.

Comment: see http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=getfeatureinfo+proxy

Comment: I am getting popups in my localhost where as on my public ip popup displaying " Some unexpected error occurred. Error text was:" . I have set my public ip with domain on proxy.cgi file. If I type myPublicip/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi I am redirected to openlayers. Can any one please tell me what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I am getting popups on my static ip. The issue is we need to set our port in the router. I am using **DLink** 2730U modem, I have set my Apache Tomcat port in  **Port Forwarding**.